# CSS Linear Background color

Tags: css

How to make a Linear Background single color (both side slope) in a div. please help

```
   background: rgb(0, 255, 113);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 42%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 0%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 42%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 0%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 42%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 0%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 42%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 0%);
background: linear-gradient(139deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 42%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 0%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/52254dte/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the gradient... then remove the gradients...

i.e. use `background: rgb(0, 255, 113);` only...  
(or whatever single color you want).

[Fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/52254dte/1/)

After clarity.... just add color stops to the gradient.....

```css
div {
 text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  
  
 background: rgb(0, 255, 113);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%, rgb(0, 255, 113) 70%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%, rgb(0, 255, 113) 70%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%, rgb(0, 255, 113) 70%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(49deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%, rgb(0, 255, 113) 70%);
background: linear-gradient(139deg, rgb(0, 255, 113) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%, rgb(0, 255, 113) 70%);}
```

```html
<div>Some Text</div>
```

Comment: I need like above image. Is it possible to do by css3?

Comment: Clarity in the question would serve you well then.

Answer (score 1):

Use a gradient, but make the actual changes in color very small (e.g. 0.1%)

```
linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 29.9%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 70%, #ff0000 70.1%, #ff0000 100%)
```

Using this method we go from 0% - 29.9% with solid color, then transition to the other color from 29.9% - 30%.

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 29.9%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 70%, #ff0000 70.1%, #ff0000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 29.9%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 70%, #ff0000 70.1%, #ff0000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 29.9%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 70%, #ff0000 70.1%, #ff0000 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```